# How to make polygon with the help of shape drawable in android?

Tags: android, polygon, shapes, xml-drawable

I want to draw Polygon with top and bottom angle in both sides like this

[image]

Comment: see this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911391/draw-a-custom-shape-in-android-using-xml

Comment: Refer this link might be its helps you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252747/android-how-to-draw-a-regular-polygon-via-xml-or-programical